# Position labels on top of bubbles in bubble bar

Tags: r

When creating a bubble graph with sizes that match specific categories I am finding it difficult to place labels exactly at the beginning of a bubble.

```
var <- c(1,2,500,2000,300,600)
data <- var %>% as.data.frame()
rownames(data) <- c("Param 1", "Param 2", "Param 3", "Param 4","Param 5","Param 6")
data <- cbind(data,rownames(data))
colnames(data) <- c("Amount","Parameter_Name")

data <- data %>%  mutate(
  Category = case_when(
    Amount < 10 ~ "Under 10",
    Amount < 500 ~ "10 - 500",
    Amount < 1000 ~ "500-1000",
    Amount < 1500 ~ ">1000",
    Amount > 1500 ~ ">1500"
  )
) 

data
ggplot(data, aes(x = Parameter_Name, y = Amount)) + 
geom_point(aes(size = Amount, color = Category)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=Parameter_Name),hjust=0.5, vjust=-1, size = 5) + 
  scale_size(range = c(1, 25)) + 
  ylim(0,2200) + 
  theme_classic(base_size = 20) + 
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank())
```

yields the following:
[image]

where the labels are in different positions.
How can I place them exactly at the top of the bubble?

Thanks!

Comment: You can consider setting ```vjust``` inside ```aes()``` which lets you set it in accordance with the size of Amount: ```geom_text(aes(label = Parameter_Name, vjust = - Amount/(10**floor(log10(max(Amount))))))```. The formula in the example is not correct, but the principle applies ...

Answer (score 0):

use position and play around: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/position_nudge.html

`position = position_nudge(y = 120))`

```
var <- c(1,2,500,2000,300,600)
data <- var %>% as.data.frame()
rownames(data) <- c("Param 1", "Param 2", "Param 3", "Param 4","Param 5","Param 6")
data <- cbind(data,rownames(data))
colnames(data) <- c("Amount","Parameter_Name")

data <- data %>%  mutate(
  Category = case_when(
    Amount < 10 ~ "Under 10",
    Amount < 500 ~ "10 - 500",
    Amount < 1000 ~ "500-1000",
    Amount < 1500 ~ ">1000",
    Amount > 1500 ~ ">1500"
  )
) 

data
ggplot(data, aes(x = Parameter_Name, y = Amount)) + 
geom_point(aes(size = Amount, color = Category)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=Parameter_Name), position = position_nudge(y = 120)) + 
  scale_size(range = c(1, 25)) + 
  ylim(0,2200) + 
  theme_classic(base_size = 20) + 
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank()
  )
```

[image]